# push data in to a multidimensional array in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array to save the data according the date and a category as follow. Then  i need to display this data in my blade view?what can i do to achieve this.

```
'2012-05-05' => array(
    'suspension' => 52,
    'transmission' => '58'
),
'2012-05-05' => array(
    'suspension' => 44,
    'transmission' => 21
```

I have done the following in my controller i want a $reportData variable to load the data.

```
 public function loadReports(Request $request)
{
    $data = ['2012-05-05','2012-05-06'];
     $salesItems = array();



        $orderItems = OrderItem::with('spare', 'order')->get();

        foreach ($orderItems as $key => $orderItem) {


            if ($orderItem->spare->retailer_id == Auth::user()->id) {
                array_push($salesItems, $orderItem);
            }


        }
        $categories = App\Categories::all();

        foreach ($data as $date) {

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $categoryValue = 0;
                foreach ($salesItems as $salesItem) {
                    if ($date == $salesItem->order->orderDate) {
                        $categoryValue += $categoryValue + $salesItem->subTotal;
                    }
                }
                //error appears as illegal offset type
                $reportData[$date][$category]=$categoryValue;



            }
        }


    return View::make('Retailer/reports')->with('categories', $categories)->with('reportData', $reportData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but looking at your code it seems that you're passing an object as array index key as 2nd level array index:

```
$reportData[$date][$category] = $categoryValue;
                   ^^^^^^^^^ this is an object
```

Dump your `$category` in the foreach loop & check if that is the case: `dd($category)`

If you're using **Eloquent** & your **Categories** Model has a name property, you'll probably want to take each category name as index value:

```
$reportData[$date][$category->name] = $categoryValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring due to the fact that you are trying to use an Object as the array's index.

As per the laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) the all method you called here '$categories = App\Category::all();' would have returned an Eloquent Collection.

So when you iterated over the $categories array and referenced $category, you were referencing an object. In PHP an array can only be indexed by either an integer or a string. So you need to change the line of code where the error is to this

```
$reportData[$date][$category->someVar] = $categoryValue;
```

Where someVar is the name of a variable on the Eloquent model Category that references its name, such as 'suspension' etc.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't answer your question you could use the Eloquent engine to make your life easier:

```
$orderItems = OrderItem::with('spare', 'order')->get();

foreach ($orderItems as $key => $orderItem) {
    if ($orderItem->spare->retailer_id == Auth::user()->id) {
        array_push($salesItems, $orderItem);
    }
}
```

can be simplified (and made more efficient) with:

```
// Store the uid to save the call.
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

// Apply the condition to the Eloquent query.
$orderItems = OrderItem::with(['spare' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
        return $query->where('retailer_id', '=', $user_id);
}, 'order'])->get();
```

The other answers are correct, but you probably also want to initialise the `$reportData` array as before you start working with it.